# How to make a slug field autocomplete in a form?

Tags: python, django

Slug field works fine but now I wont it to autocoplete in the form in the site administration. The slug field is connected with the field naslov.
I wont that text appear on the field slug when I write on the field naslov but with a hyphen and all lowercase.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    naslov = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    opis = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    datum_objave = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    opsirnije_text = models.TextField(max_length=20000)

    def __str__(self):             
        return self.naslov

    def spremi(self):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.naslov)
        super(test, self).save()

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.datum_objave >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Question


class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   question_fields = {"slug": ("naslov",)}

admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### admin.py

```
from .models import Question

class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("naslov",)}


admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```